# Dart/Flutter lock File for read and write

Tags: flutter, file, dart, file-locking

since this a rather usual Problem, I think I am missing something easy, but:

How can I lock a (text) file "fileFrom" in dart, to read the content, write it to another file "fileTo" and delete the content in fileFrom.
I need to lock fileFrom, because a separate thread will try to write logs in fileFrom.

I think, if I first use File.readAsStringSync() and File.writeAsStringSync() that would give another Thread the option to write in to FileA in between the two function calls, wouldn't it?

```
Future<void> _moveFileContent(File fileFrom, File fileTo) async {
var string = fileFrom.readAsStringSync();
fileFrom.writeAsStringSync("");
fileTo.writeAsStringSync(string, mode: FileMode.append);
}
```

When I use File.openSync() the RandomAccessFile dosen't give me any data. (FileFrom has contet at this point)

```
var raf = fileFrom.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
try{
  List<int> buffer = [];
  raf.readIntoSync(buffer);
  // buffer.length is 0
  var length = raf.lengthSync();
  // length is 0
}catch (e){
  locateLogger().error(e.toString());
} finally{
  raf.closeSync();
}
```

What am I missing? Or would it make more sense to use a database in the first place?

Comment: I think I found my stupidity. Please correct me, if I am wrong:

Dart runs on a single threat. So the async functions go to a stack from wich they are worked when ever the CPU has time for it. So separate async function can't really operate simultan.
In conclusion, as long as one function call is working another function call can't run. So there is no need to lock that file as long as all is handled in one function call.

Answer (score 0):

Start working in something like this:

```
  final File fileToR = new File("path_1");
  final File fileToW = new File("path_2");
  RandomAccessFile rar = fileToR.openSync(mode: FileMode.read);
  RandomAccessFile raw = fileToW.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
  try {
    List<int> buffer = [];
    while (rar.readIntoSync(buffer) > 0) raw.writeFromSync(buffer);
    RandomAccessFile fileFinal = File(rar.path).openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
    fileFinal.truncateSync(0);
  } catch (e) {
    // writelog(e.toString());
  } finally {
    // writelog(e.toString());
  }
```